# Find repeated elements from two lists and mark them in text file while keeping order

Tags: python

I have two lists: `list2` and `intersection_set`.

`intersection_set` is a sorted list.

Now I try to create `list3` with marked common items from `list2` and `intersection_set.` The sequence in `list3` must be the same as in `list2`.
This is my piece of code:

```
for item in intersection_set:
    for tmp in list2:
        if tmp == item:
            list3 += " [", tmp, "] "                #mark with []
        else:
            list3 += " ", str(tmp).zfill(4), " "    #fill to zeros
```

But there is a problem. List3 has looped numbers.

I realize that my way of thinking is probably wrong.

1. How can I fix this code?
2. Is there another way to mark numbers in a text file? (some of 'character background' in simple text file - is this possible? For example white numbers on black background?)

Comment: Please add an example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning 1), you should be able to omit the loop (which caused the duplications) through `intersection_set` and use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
for tmp in list2:
    if tmp in intersection_set:
        list3 += " [", tmp, "] "                #mark with []
    else:
        list3 += " ", str(tmp).zfill(4), " "    #fill to zeros
```

For 2), if you want to emphasize the number,

- you can use any combination of characters (like `[`) that you like.
- If you use UTF-8, you can combine characters, f.ex. underscore and the number, which are displayed on the same space, example: `a` plus [COMBINING LOW LINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underline)
- just follow the Markdown convention and use `*` for emphasis and `/` for italics

Comment: Thank You very much. This is the answer what I'm looking for.

Comment: For 2nd question: I think is possible white numbers on black background in simple text file? Maybe in UTF-8 or another encoding format...

Comment: @Janix: I have not heard of a generic feature for a simple text file. (It might be possible for specific editors like emacs). Maybe ask another question.

Comment: @Janix: maybe Unicode diacritics might work for you (underline text etc).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood your question.
You want list3 to be the list of items in list 2 that exist in intersection_set.
If so:

```
list3 = [" ["+item+"] " if item in intersection_set else " "+str(item).zfill(4)+ " " for item in list2]
```

Tha would make list 3 a list of strings though, is that what you want?